# Подсчёт непересекающихся кругов на белом фоне

Tags: php, нейронные-сети, распознавание-образов

Пользователь загружает картинку, на которой полно заполненных кругов разных оттенков серого на белом фоне. Круги не пересекаются, но почти всегда касаются друг друга.

[image: circle packing]

**Надо "сосчитать" круги и определить радиус и яркость каждого.**

Как подступиться к такой задаче? Есть ли подходящая библиотека или класс, чтобы реализовать это на PHP? Приходилось ли Вам решать похожую задачу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такой вариант. Можно "рисовать" виртуальный квадрат ABСD, увеличивая его размер в цикле (из вершины A -- левой верхней -- но не из центра), делая проверки на каждой итерации:

1. **[исключить]** как минимум в трех вершинах цвет -- белый
2. в центре квадрата цвет -- не белый
3. в серединах всех четырех отрезков AB, BC, CD и DA цвет -- не белый

**UPD**
Первое условие надо исключить, не делать на него проверку, ибо если в двух любых вершинах окажутся другие круги -- провал. 
Можно попробовать обойтись условием №3.

Как только все условия будут удовлетворены, считать, что круг найден. После этого точки B, C и D нужно сбросить, а вершину A сдвинуть вправо по OX, скажем, на треть диаметра последнего найденного круга. Так продолжать, пока координаты точки A по OX меньше ширины картинки. Когда достигнешь "конца строки", надо сместить точку A на [?] пикселей вниз по OY -- на следующую строку.

Comment: Это не гарантированный поиск (он будет искать при примерно одинаковых радиусах кругов). Например круг с центром (10, 10) и радиусом 6, к нему примыкают образуя крест четыре круга с радиусом 2 и координатами (10, 2), (10, 18), (2, 10), (18, 10) весь этот крест Ваш метод поиска примет как круг радиусом 10 с центром (10, 10).

Comment: Что-то не понимаю. Поясните, синий и фиолетовый кружочки учтутся?
![пример](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3533396/SO/finding_circle.png)

Comment: Алгоритм основывается на том, что квадрат ABCD должен описывать искомый круг -- это должно считаться "правильным". То есть, квадрат должен начинать рисоваться из A = (7, 7). При этом, A всегда будет оставаться в этой точке, пока не сместится сам квадрат.


Описанную ошибку можно исключить, введя проверку: точка A -- белая, центр -- белый, точка C -- не белая; при соблюдении этих условий прерывать цикл, считая что квадрат изначально не был нарисован "правильно".


Конечно же, предложенный мной вариант нельзя считать окончательным, он нуждается в дополнительной обкатке в полевых условиях.

Comment: Когда писал предыдущий комментарий, еще не видел ответа @sergiks с картинкой. Да, sergiks, синий и фиолетовый кружочки учтутся. Но если в точке C окажется еще какой-то кружок, то не учтется (неправильно определится радиус) большого серого круга. Так что, да, мой вариант не подходит.

Comment: Но в общем-то идея с квадратом, по-моему, неплохая. Может, можно исключить условие №1...

Comment: Вариант с квадратом плох тем, что он оперирует с областью вне круга. А там может быть всё, что угодно. Поэтому мне кажется лучше не вылезать с алгоритмом за пределы круга. Либо обучить нейронную сеть на примерах, и не понимать, как же она работает, главное, что работает )

Answer (score 1):

ну, первое, что приходит в голову - поднять контраст(белый - 1, остальное - 0), потом слегка размыть(1-3 пикселя, подбирается в зависимости от "честности" касания) и снова поднять контраст, но на этот раз черный - 0, остальное - 1. Таким образом мы гарантированно избавимся от прикосновений. Потом тупо посчитать входы-выходы в темные области.

Способ долгий и затратный, но на приведеной картинке должен справиться быстро.

Comment: все OCR'ы строятся на обучаемых нейронных сетях, вроде бы. Для моей скромной задачи это перебор, вероятно. 
Я бы смотрел иначе: находил не-фоновые области, ставил точку и "растил" окружность из неё, смещая центр, если это помогает окружности вырасти ещё, не вылезая на фон или за область рисунка.

Comment: А как вы собираетесь "растить" окружность? =) Если рисовать все большие и большие круги, смещая центр, вдоль перпендикуляра хорды, боюсь, это будет еще сложнее, чем то, что предложил я. =/

Comment: "Рисовать" исключительно виртуально. На деле, проверять яркость 8/16/32 точек расположенных на этой окружности, если они всё ещё темные — мы внутри. Одна-две стали фоном - значит, вылезли из круга. Итерируя с малым шагом вполне можно вписываться в нарисованные круги почти без ошибок. Наверное : )